# I can't use the letter "d" on commandline

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, manjaro, input

When I'm logged as **user** or **root** I cannot type the letter <kbd>d</kbd> on a terminal, and if I paste a word containing it the **d** is erased.

I can type it in the graphical interface (**i3wm**) and in non-graphical terminals, the last only before I log as user or root.

I'm on **Manjaro 17.06 i3 Community Edition**.

My [~/.basrhc](https://hastebin.com/ekorarinoh.bash)

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

colors() {
    local fgc bgc vals seq0

    printf "Color escapes are %s\n" '\e[${value};...;${value}m'
    printf "Values 30..37 are \e[33mforeground colors\e[m\n"
    printf "Values 40..47 are \e[43mbackground colors\e[m\n"
    printf "Value  1 gives a  \e[1mbold-faced look\e[m\n\n"

    # foreground colors
    for fgc in {30..37}; do
        # background colors
        for bgc in {40..47}; do
            fgc=${fgc#37} # white
            bgc=${bgc#40} # black

            vals="${fgc:+$fgc;}${bgc}"
            vals=${vals%%;}

            seq0="${vals:+\e[${vals}m}"
            printf "  %-9s" "${seq0:-(default)}"
            printf " ${seq0}TEXT\e[m"
            printf " \e[${vals:+${vals+$vals;}}1mBOLD\e[m"
        done
        echo; echo
    done
}

[[ -f ~/.extend.bashrc ]] && . ~/.extend.bashrc

[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion   ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

alias t='python /home/gato/tasks/t/t.py --task-dir ~/tasks --list task'
alias pacu='sudo rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck'
alias tt='clear'

export PS1="[$(t | wc -l | sed -e's/ *//')] $PS1"
```

My i3wm [configuration file](https://hastebin.com/ocahezetuj.bash)

```
# Please see http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!

    # Set mod key (Mod1=<Alt>, Mod4=<Super>)
    set $mod Mod4

    # set default desktop layout (default is tiling)
    # workspace_layout tabbed <stacking|tabbed>

    # Configure border style <normal|1pixel|pixel xx|none|pixel>
    new_window pixel 1
    new_float normal

    # Hide borders
    hide_edge_borders none

    # change borders
    bindsym $mod+u border none
    bindsym $mod+y border pixel 1
    bindsym $mod+n border normal

    # Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
    # is used in the bar {} block below.
    font xft:Noto Sans 10

    # Use Mouse+$mod to drag floating windows
    floating_modifier $mod

    # start a terminalM
    bindsym $mod+Return exec terminal

    # kill focused window
    bindsym $mod+Shift+q kill

    # start program launcher
    bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id dmenu_recency

    # launch categorized menu
    bindsym $mod+z exec --no-startup-id morc_menu

    ################################################################################################
    ## sound-section - DO NOT EDIT if you wish to automatically upgrade Alsa -> Pulseaudio later! ##
    ################################################################################################

    #exec --no-startup-id volumeicon
    #bindsym $mod+Ctrl+m exec terminal -e 'alsamixer'
    exec --no-startup-id pulseaudio
    exec --no-startup-id pa-applet
    #bindsym $mod+Ctrl+m exec pavucontrol

    ################################################################################################

    # Screen brightness controls
    # bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec "xbacklight -inc 10; notify-send 'brightness up'"
    # bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec "xbacklight -dec 10; notify-send 'brightness down'"

    # Start Applications
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+b exec terminal -e 'bmenu'
    #bindsym $mod+F2 exec palemoon
    bindsym $mod+F5 exec pcmanfm
    # bindsym $mod+F3 exec ranger
    bindsym $mod+Shift+F3 exec gksu pcmanfm
    bindsym $mod+F6 exec terminal -e 'mocp'
    bindsym $mod+t exec --no-startup-id pkill compton
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+t exec --no-startup-id compton -b
    bindsym $mod+Shift+d --release exec "killall dunst; exec notify-send 'restart dunst'"
    bindsym Print exec --no-startup-id i3-scrot
    bindsym $mod+Print --release exec --no-startup-id i3-scrot -w
    bindsym $mod+Shift+Print --release exec --no-startup-id i3-scrot -s
    bindsym $mod+Shift+h exec xdg-open /usr/share/doc/manjaro/i3_help.pdf
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+x --release exec --no-startup-id xkill

    # focus_follows_mouse no

    # change focus
    bindsym $mod+j focus left
    bindsym $mod+k focus down
    bindsym $mod+l focus up
    bindsym $mod+semicolon focus right

    # alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
    bindsym $mod+Left focus left
    bindsym $mod+Down focus down
    bindsym $mod+Up focus up
    bindsym $mod+Right focus right

    # move focused window
    bindsym $mod+Shift+j move left
    bindsym $mod+Shift+k move down
    bindsym $mod+Shift+l move up
    bindsym $mod+Shift+semicolon move right

    # alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
    bindsym $mod+Shift+Left move left
    bindsym $mod+Shift+Down move down
    bindsym $mod+Shift+Up move up
    bindsym $mod+Shift+Right move right

    # workspace back and forth (with/without active container)
    workspace_auto_back_and_forth yes
    bindsym $mod+b workspace back_and_forth
    bindsym $mod+Shift+b move container to workspace back_and_forth; workspace back_and_forth

    # split orientation
    bindsym $mod+h split h;exec notify-send 'tile horizontally'
    bindsym $mod+v split v;exec notify-send 'tile vertically'
    bindsym $mod+q split toggle

    # toggle fullscreen mode for the focused container
    bindsym $mod+f fullscreen toggle

    # change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
    bindsym $mod+s layout stacking
    bindsym $mod+w layout tabbed
    bindsym $mod+e layout toggle split

    # toggle tiling / floating
    bindsym $mod+Shift+space floating toggle

    # change focus between tiling / floating windows
    bindsym $mod+space focus mode_toggle

    # toggle sticky
    bindsym $mod+Shift+s sticky toggle

    # focus the parent container
    bindsym $mod+a focus parent

    # move the currently focused window to the scratchpad
    bindsym $mod+Shift+minus move scratchpad

    # Show the next scratchpad window or hide the focused scratchpad window.
    # If there are multiple scratchpad windows, this command cycles through them.
    bindsym $mod+minus scratchpad show

    #navigate workspaces next / previous
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+Right workspace next
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+Left workspace prev

    # Workspace names
    # to display names or symbols instead of plain workspace numbers you can use
    # something like: set $ws1 1:mail
    #                 set $ws2 2:
    set $ws1 1: 1 Browsing
    set $ws2 2: 2 Creation
    set $ws3 3: 3 Sistema
    set $ws4 4: 4 Spotify
    set $ws5 5: 5 Video
    set $ws6 6: 6
    set $ws7 7: 7
    set $ws8 7: 8

    # switch to workspace
    bindsym $mod+1 workspace $ws1
    bindsym $mod+2 workspace $ws2
    bindsym $mod+3 workspace $ws3
    bindsym $mod+4 workspace $ws4
    bindsym $mod+5 workspace $ws5
    bindsym $mod+6 workspace $ws6
    bindsym $mod+7 workspace $ws7
    bindsym $mod+8 workspace $ws8

    # Move focused container to workspace
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+1 move container to workspace $ws1
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+2 move container to workspace $ws2
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+3 move container to workspace $ws3
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+4 move container to workspace $ws4
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+5 move container to workspace $ws5
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+6 move container to workspace $ws6
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+7 move container to workspace $ws7
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+8 move container to workspace $ws8

    # Move to workspace with focused container
    bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace $ws1; workspace $ws1
    bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace $ws2; workspace $ws2
    bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace $ws3; workspace $ws3
    bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace $ws4; workspace $ws4
    bindsym $mod+Shift+5 move container to workspace $ws5; workspace $ws5
    bindsym $mod+Shift+6 move container to workspace $ws6; workspace $ws6
    bindsym $mod+Shift+7 move container to workspace $ws7; workspace $ws7
    bindsym $mod+Shift+8 move container to workspace $ws7; workspace $ws8

    # Open applications on specific workspaces
    # assign [class="Thunderbird"] $ws1
    # assign [class="Pale moon"] $ws2
    # assign [class="Pcmanfm"] $ws3
    # assign [class="Skype"] $ws5

    assign [class="Google-chrome"] $ws1
    assign [class="Subl3"] $ws2
    #assign [class="Catfish"] $ws3
    assign [class="Pcmanfm"] $ws3
    assign [class="keepassxc"] $ws3
    #assign [class="Pamac-manager"] $ws3
    #assign [class="octopi"] $ws3
    #assign [class="vcl"] $ws5
    #assign [class="Kodi"] $ws5
    #assign [id="window id # 0x4800002"] $ws4

    # Open specific applications in floating mode
    for_window [title="alsamixer"] floating enable border pixel 1
    for_window [class="Calamares"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="Clipgrab"] floating enable
    for_window [title="File Transfer*"] floating enable
    for_window [class="Galculator"] floating enable border pixel 1
    for_window [class="GParted"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [title="i3_help"] floating enable sticky enable border normal
    for_window [class="Lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings"] floating enable
    for_window [class="Lxappearance"] floating enable sticky enable border normal
    for_window [class="Manjaro-hello"] floating enable
    for_window [class="Manjaro Settings Manager"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [title="MuseScore: Play Panel"] floating enable
    for_window [class="Nitrogen"] floating enable sticky enable border normal
    for_window [class="Oblogout"] fullscreen enable
    #for_window [class="octopi"] floating enable
    for_window [title="About Pale Moon"] floating enable
    #for_window [class="Pamac-manager"] floating enable
    for_window [class="Pavucontrol"] floating enable
    for_window [class="qt5ct"] floating enable sticky enable border normal
    for_window [class="Qtconfig-qt4"] floating enable sticky enable border normal
    for_window [class="Simple-scan"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="(?i)System-config-printer.py"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="Skype"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="Thus"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="Timeset-gui"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="(?i)virtualbox"] floating enable border normal
    for_window [class="Xfburn"] floating enable

    # switch to workspace with urgent window automatically
    for_window [urgent=latest] focus

    # reload the configuration file
    bindsym $mod+Shift+c reload

    # restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
    bindsym $mod+Shift+r restart

    # exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
    bindsym $mod+Control+Shift+e exec exit #"i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -b 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

    # Set shut down, restart and locking features
    bindsym $mod+0 mode "$mode_system"
    set $mode_system (l)ock, (e)xit, switch_(u)ser, (s)uspend, (h)ibernate, (r)eboot, (Shift+s)hutdown
    mode "$mode_system" {
        bindsym l exec --no-startup-id i3exit lock, mode "default"
        bindsym s exec --no-startup-id i3exit suspend, mode "default"
        bindsym u exec --no-startup-id i3exit switch_user, mode "default"
        bindsym e exec --no-startup-id i3exit logout, mode "default"
        bindsym h exec --no-startup-id i3exit hibernate, mode "default"
        bindsym r exec --no-startup-id i3exit reboot, mode "default"
        bindsym Shift+s exec --no-startup-id i3exit shutdown, mode "default"

        # exit system mode: "Enter" or "Escape"
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym Escape mode "default"
    }

    # Resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
    bindsym $mod+r mode "resize"
    mode "resize" {
            # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode
            # Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
            # Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
            # Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
            # Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
            bindsym j resize shrink width 5 px or 5 ppt
            bindsym k resize grow height 5 px or 5 ppt
            bindsym l resize shrink height 5 px or 5 ppt
            bindsym semicolon resize grow width 5 px or 5 ppt

            # same bindings, but for the arrow keys
            bindsym Left resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym Down resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym Up resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym Right resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

            # exit resize mode: Enter or Escape
            bindsym Return mode "default"
            bindsym Escape mode "default"
    }

    # Lock screen
    bindsym $mod+ctrl+9 exec --no-startup-id blurlock

    # Autostart applications
    exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
    exec --no-startup-id nitrogen --restore; sleep 1; compton -b
    #exec --no-startup-id manjaro-hello
    exec --no-startup-id nm-applet
    exec --no-startup-id xfce4-power-manager
    exec --no-startup-id pamac-tray
    exec --no-startup-id clipit
    # exec --no-startup-id blueman-applet
    # exec_always --no-startup-id sbxkb
    exec --no-startup-id start_conky_maia
    # exec --no-startup-id start_conky_green
    exec --no-startup-id xautolock -time 10 -locker blurlock
    exec_always --no-startup-id ff-theme-util
    exec_always --no-startup-id fix_xcursor

    # Color palette used for the terminal ( ~/.extend.Xresources file )
    # Colors are gathered based on the documentation:
    # https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#xresources
    # Change the variable name at the place you want to match the color
    # of your terminal like this:
    # [example]
    # If you want your bar to have the same background color as your 
    # terminal background change the line 362 from:
    # background  $i3_background
    # to:
    # background $term_background
    # Same logic applied to everything else.
    set_from_resource $term_background background
    set_from_resource $term_foreground foreground
    set_from_resource $term_color0     color0
    set_from_resource $term_color1     color1
    set_from_resource $term_color2     color2
    set_from_resource $term_color3     color3
    set_from_resource $term_color4     color4
    set_from_resource $term_color5     color5
    set_from_resource $term_color6     color6
    set_from_resource $term_color7     color7
    set_from_resource $term_color8     color8
    set_from_resource $term_color9     color9
    set_from_resource $term_color10    color10
    set_from_resource $term_color11    color11
    set_from_resource $term_color12    color12
    set_from_resource $term_color13    color13
    set_from_resource $term_color14    color14
    set_from_resource $term_color15    color15

    # Color palette used for i3 
    # Variables are set based on the documentation:
    # https://i3wm.org/dovs/userguide.html#variables
    # Changing the value of one of the variables will
    # effect all the areas with the same color.
    set $i3_background      #2b2c2b
    set $i3_text            #f9faf9
    set $i3_separator       #454947
    set $i3_color1          #f9faf9
    set $i3_color2          #595b5b
    set $i3_color3          #353836
    set $i3_color4          #16a085
    set $i3_color5          #fdf6e3
    set $i3_color6          #eee8d5
    set $i3_color7          #e5201d
    set $i3_color8          #808380
    set $i3_color9          #434745
    set $i3_color10         #454948
    set $i3_color11         #80fff9
    set $i3_color12         #fdf6e3
    set $i3_color13         #cb4b16
    set $i3_color14         #268bd2
    set $i3_color15         #000000
    set $i3_color16         #ffffff
    set $i3_color17         #0c0c0c

    # Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status if available)
    bar {
        i3bar_command i3bar
        status_command i3status
        position bottom

    ## please set your primary output first. Example: 'xrandr --output eDP1 --primary'
    #   tray_output primary
    #   tray_output eDP1

        bindsym button4 nop
        bindsym button5 nop
        font xft:Noto Sans 10.5
        strip_workspace_numbers yes

        colors {
            background $i3_background
            statusline $i3_text
            separator  $i3_separator

    #                           border     backgr.        text
            focused_workspace   $i3_color1 $i3_color4     $i3_text
            active_workspace    $i3_color2 $i3_color3     $i3_color5
            inactive_workspace  $i3_color2 $i3_color3     $i3_color6
            binding_mode        $i3_color8 $i3_background $i3_text
            urgent_workspace    $i3_color4 $i3_color5     $i3_color7
        }
    }

    # hide/unhide i3status bar
    bindsym $mod+m bar mode toggle

    # Theme colors
    # class                 border      backgr.     text        indic.      child_border
    client.focused          $i3_color8  $i3_color8  $i3_color11 $i3_color12
    client.focused_inactive $i3_color9  $i3_color9  $i3_color4  $i3_color10
    client.unfocused        $i3_color9  $i3_color9  $i3_color4  $i3_color10
    client.urgent           $i3_color13 $i3_color12 $i3_color4  $i3_color14
    client.placeholder      $i3_color15 $i3_color17 $i3_color16 $i3_color15 $i3_color17

    client.background       $i3_background

    #############################
    ### settings for i3-gaps: ###
    #############################

    # Set inner/outer gaps
    gaps inner 10
    gaps outer -4

    # Additionally, you can issue commands with the following syntax. This is useful to bind keys to changing the gap size.
    # gaps inner|outer current|all set|plus|minus <px>
    # gaps inner all set 10
    # gaps outer all plus 5

    # Smart gaps (gaps used if only more than one container on the workspace)
    smart_gaps on

    # Smart borders (draw borders around container only if it is not the only container on this workspace) 
    # on|no_gaps (on=always activate and no_gaps=only activate if the gap size to the edge of the screen is 0)
    smart_borders on

    # Press $mod+Shift+g to enter the gap mode. Choose o or i for modifying outer/inner gaps. Press one of + / - (in-/decrement for current workspace) or 0 (remove gaps for current workspace). If you also press Shift with these keys, the change will be global for all workspaces.
    set $mode_gaps Gaps: (o) outer, (i) inner
    set $mode_gaps_outer Outer Gaps: +|-|0 (local), Shift + +|-|0 (global)
    set $mode_gaps_inner Inner Gaps: +|-|0 (local), Shift + +|-|0 (global)
    bindsym $mod+Shift+g mode "$mode_gaps"

    mode "$mode_gaps" {
            bindsym o      mode "$mode_gaps_outer"
            bindsym i      mode "$mode_gaps_inner"
            bindsym Return mode "default"
            bindsym Escape mode "default"
    }
    mode "$mode_gaps_inner" {
            bindsym plus  gaps inner current plus 5
            bindsym minus gaps inner current minus 5
            bindsym 0     gaps inner current set 0

            bindsym Shift+plus  gaps inner all plus 5
            bindsym Shift+minus gaps inner all minus 5
            bindsym Shift+0     gaps inner all set 0

            bindsym Return mode "default"
            bindsym Escape mode "default"
    } 
    mode "$mode_gaps_outer" {
            bindsym plus  gaps outer current plus 5
            bindsym minus gaps outer current minus 5
            bindsym 0     gaps outer current set 0

            bindsym Shift+plus  gaps outer all plus 5
            bindsym Shift+minus gaps outer all minus 5
            bindsym Shift+0     gaps outer all set 0

            bindsym Return mode "default"
            bindsym Escape mode "default"
    }

    # Meus atalhos
    bindsym $mod+shift+w exec leafpad
    bindsym $mod+F2 exec google-chrome-stable
    bindsym $mod+F3 exec google-chrome-stable file:///home/gato/Documents/i3%20Documentation/i3_%20i3%20User%E2%80%99s%20Guide.html
    bindsym $mod+F9 exec subl3
    bindsym $mod+F10 exec geany /home/gato/.i3/config

    # Atalhos do Ponymix
    bindsym $mod+F11 exec ponymix decrease 15
    bindsym $mod+F12 exec ponymix increase 15

    #bindsym $mod+F4 exec opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text

    # Startup Applications
    exec google-chrome-stable
    exec synapse -s
    exec guake
    exec keepassxc
    exec pcmanfm
    exec autokey-gtk
    exec megasync
    exec ponymix

    # Pulse Audio controls
    #bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5% #increase sound volume
    ##bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 -5% #decrease sound volume
    #bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle # mute sound

    # Sreen brightness controls
    #bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
    #bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness

    # Touchpad controls
    #bindsym XF86TouchpadToggle exec /some/path/toggletouchpad.sh # toggle touchpad

    # Media player controls
    #bindsym $Ctrl+Alt+ePlay exec playerctl play
    #bindsym XF86AudioPause exec playerctl pause
    #bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
    #bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous

    # Video Config - Single
    #!/bin/sh
    exec_always xrandr --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output eDP1 --off --output VIRTUAL1 --off
```

My **~/.extend.bashrc**

```
# ~/.extend.bashrc
#

# Change the window title of X terminals
case ${TERM} in
    xterm*|rxvt*|Eterm*|aterm|kterm|gnome*|interix|konsole*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/\~}\007"'
        ;;
    screen*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/\~}\033\\"'
        ;;
esac

use_color=true

# Set colorful PS1 only on colorful terminals.
# dircolors --print-database uses its own built-in database
# instead of using /etc/DIR_COLORS.  Try to use the external file
# first to take advantage of user additions.  Use internal bash
# globbing instead of external grep binary.
safe_term=${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}   # sanitize TERM
match_lhs=""
[[ -f ~/.dir_colors   ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(<~/.dir_colors)"
[[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(</etc/DIR_COLORS)"
[[ -z ${match_lhs}    ]] \
    && type -P dircolors >/dev/null \
    && match_lhs=$(dircolors --print-database)
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true

if ${use_color} ; then
    # Enable colors for ls, etc.  Prefer ~/.dir_colors #64489
    if type -P dircolors >/dev/null ; then
        if [[ -f ~/.dir_colors ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors)
        elif [[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
        fi
    fi

    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;31m\][\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='\[\033[01;32m\][\u@\h\[\033[01;37m\] \W\[\033[01;32m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi

    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --colour=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --colour=auto'
else
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        # show root@ when we don't have colors
        PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
    else
        PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
    fi
fi

unset use_color safe_term match_lhs sh

alias cp="cp -i"                          # confirm before overwriting something
alias df='df -h'                          # human-readable sizes
alias free='free -m'                      # show sizes in MB
alias np='nano -w PKGBUILD'
alias more=less

xhost +local:root > /dev/null 2>&1

complete -cf sudo

# Bash won't get SIGWINCH if another process is in the foreground.
# Enable checkwinsize so that bash will check the terminal size when
# it regains control.  #65623
# http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/bash/FAQ (E11)
shopt -s checkwinsize

shopt -s expand_aliases


# export QT_SELECT=4

# Enable history appending instead of overwriting.  #139609
shopt -s histappend

#
# # ex - archive extractor
# # usage: ex <file>
ex ()
{
  if [ -f $1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
      *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1   ;;
      *.rar)       unrar x $1   ;;
      *.gz)        gunzip $1    ;;
      *.tar)       tar xf $1    ;;
      *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tgz)       tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.zip)       unzip $1     ;;
      *.Z)         uncompress $1;;
      *.7z)        7z x $1      ;;
      *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via ex()" ;;
    esac
  else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
  fi
}

# better yaourt colors
export YAOURT_COLORS="nb=1:pkg=1:ver=1;32:lver=1;45:installed=1;42:grp=1;34:od=1;41;5:votes=1;44:dsc=0:other=1;35"

# fix "xdg-open fork-bomb" export your preferred browser from here
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/palemoon

alias con='nano $HOME/.i3/config'
alias comp='nano $HOME/.config/compton.conf'
alias fixit='sudo rm -f /var/lib/pacman/db.lck'
alias inst='sudo pacman -S'
alias la='ls -la --group-directories-first --time-style=+"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" --color=auto -F'
alias ll='ls -l --group-directories-first --time-style=+"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" --color=auto -F'
alias mirrors='sudo pacman-mirrors -g'
alias printer='system-config-printer'
alias update='yaourt -Syua'
```

Update: **d** works fine on zsh.

Comment: Perhaps your keyboard is faulty?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not possible. I can type normally while not logged in. I also work with a laptop, external monitor and USB keyboard. I can't type "d" with both keyboards.

Comment: The `.bashrc` link doesn't work. Please post the files directly in the question instead of at remote links.

Comment: Do you have an `stty` command in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Sorry, I thought linking was the correct way. I opened in an anonymous window and it worked. I will update the question, thanks.

Comment: What about `~/.inputrc`? What's in `~/.extend.bashrc`? Does the key work in another terminal emulator? Does it work in applications other than a terminal? Does it work if you run `cat` in the terminal?

Comment: I does not work in any terminal. Yes, it works in other applications It **does work if  I run cat. I will update the op with .inputrc.

Comment: I couldn't' find a .inputrc in my system, but I included my .extended.bashrc in the original posting.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/616525/i-cant-type-a-b-when-im-in-the-command-line.

Comment: Mr. S: I'm afraid I have a speech impediment. I can't pronounce the letter B.
Mr. B: Uh, C.
Mr. S: Yes, that's right, B. It's all due to a trauma I suffered when I was a sboolboy. I was attacked by a Siamese bat.
Mr. B: Uh, ah, a Siamese cat.
Mr. S: No, a Siamese bat. They're more dangerous. 
Mr. B: Listen, can you say the letter K?
Mr. S: Oh, yes. Khaki, kettle, Kipling, Khomeini, Kellog's Born Flakes.
Mr. B: Well, why don't you say the letter K instead of the letter C? 
....
Mr. S: Oh, it's very good! I never thought of that before. What a silly bunt.

Answer (score 2):

Try entering the 'd' key with Alt+100 on the numeric keypad, and use it to run the `dumpkeys` command:

```
dumpkeys -1 --keys-only | grep e..32 | head -n 1
```

In alternative you can try

```
$( echo DUMPKEYS | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" ) -1 --keys-only | grep e..32 | head -n 1
```

to do the same thing without typing a lowercase d.
It should report that plain keycode 32 maps to "+d". Otherwise you've got a funny `loadkeys` command somewhere, *probably* (but not surely) under `/etc`, in the user loaded commands (e.g. `/etc/bash.bashrc` or similar).

Seeing as this is the first character of your name, I would not rule out a prank.

Comment: Alt + 100 on my numeric keypad just types "100" on the terminal. Even if copy paste a "d" in the terminal it just erases every Ds. I can type uppercase D, though. Could I do something with that?

Comment: I says `dumpkeys`